How to close multiple open folders in Outliner?
Every time I open Blender, all my folders in the outliner are open. Why might that be happening? Is there a way of preventing that?
How would I close all the foleders simultaneously as opposed to one by one?
Thank you!

With your mouse cursor over the Outliner panel try Shft + A . This should toggle opening (expanding) and closing (collapsing) all Collections (folders) in the Outliner..

If you save your Blender file with all the collections collapsed then it should open that way.

Unfortunately these suggestions didn't work for me but the Minus & Plus do

You can hit minus on numpad or clic and drag down on the arrows in front of collections

Nice one, Thats even simpler than what I was suggesting. Numpad minus key to collapse and plus key to expand. :)
